# How does this endian conversion work?

Tags: c-preprocessor, endianness, qnx

A QNX library called gfpr.h contains the line

```
#define ENDIAN_LE16(__x)    (__x)
```

which is used as follows

```
var1 = ENDIAN_LE16(var1);
```

to convert the endianness of (unsigned short) var1.  How does this work?  `__x` and `x__` must have some special meaning to the preprocessor?

Answer (score 2):

`__x` does not have a special meaning.  [`ENDIAN_LE16`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/e/endian_le16.html) is a macro that makes a place to change endianness without changing your source code.  Each build target can have a different version of `gfpr.h` specific for that target.

You must be compiling for a little-endian machine, so `ENDIAN_LE16` doesn't need to make any changes.  It just leaves its argument (`__x`) unchanged.  If you were compiling for a big-endian target, `ENDIAN_LE16` would be defined to swap the bytes of its argument.  Something like:

```
#define ENDIAN_LE16(__x) ( (((x) & 0xff) << 8) | (((x) >> 8) & 0xff) )
```

That way, by changing which target's `gfpr.h` file you include, you get the right results without having to change your source code.

**Edit** Per the [file you're probably looking at](https://github.com/tyrantyr/onda_qnx/blob/master/bsp-TI-omap3730-Beagle-xm-src/prebuilt/usr/include/gfpr/gfpr.h), [`ENDIAN_BE32`](https://github.com/tyrantyr/onda_qnx/blob/master/bsp-TI-omap3730-Beagle-xm-src/prebuilt/usr/include/gfpr/gfpr.h#L60) invokes [`ENDIAN_RET32`](https://github.com/tyrantyr/onda_qnx/blob/master/bsp-TI-omap3730-Beagle-xm-src/prebuilt/usr/include/gfpr/gfpr.h#L37), which twiddles bits in a way similar to what I showed above.